# Where install SQLiteAndroidDatabase.java file?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying use [`Cordova-sqlite-storage`](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) in my `Phonegap` application

I have included `SQLitePlugin.js` in my application page, but when I execute the documentation demo code, it is returning this error message in console:

```
[console.log] OPEN database: Database
[console.log] new transaction is waiting for open operation
[console.log] OPEN database: Database failed. aborting any pending transactions
[console.log] Could not open database
```

This is code executed:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", -1);

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
      console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

      tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
        console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
        console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
      });

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

In the documentation is write:

```
Install SQLiteAndroidDatabase.java and SQLitePlugin.java from src/android/io/liteglue into src/io/liteglue subdirectory
```

But I can't find `src` folder in my project

Comment: did you find a solution yet?

Comment: no yet, I saved in `localStorage`, but maybe this can help you http://pouchdb.com

Comment: `pouchdb` is a database like `mongoDb`, I don't have experience in `pouchDb`, but look like me very practical

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run it in browser?

In device it will work but in browser it wont't!!

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment only. Once you earn reputation you will be able to comment.

Comment: Ofcourse I wanted to comment only but i don't have sufficient points to do that

Comment: its completely understandable. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead,  [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)